# Rails 3 - respond_to as JS and flash message

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, flash, render

After send a form I will process a data from form and wanna to render an action as JS. This work me. 
But + this functionality I would like to add a flash message yet. I try to do it as follows:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @save.update_attributes(params[:data])   
    format.js {     
      flash[:notice] = 'The article was successfully updated.'
      render :update do |page|; page << "$('#my_div').html('#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'article'))}');" end
     }
    format.html {} 
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @data.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

Now the flash message is not displayed. Could anyone help me, why not? I tried the line with `flash[:notice]` move to out of `format.js` block, but the is still not displayed...

Could you help me, please, why?r

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the point 2.2.10 of the documentation :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

render :js => "$('#my_div').html('#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'article'))}');"